# Size of Output vector from AvgW2V Vectorizer is less than Size of Input data

Tags: machine-learning, feature-extraction, word2vec, text

[image]Hi,
I have been seeing this problem for quite some time. Whenever I tried vectorizing input text data though avgw2v vectorization technique. The size of vectorized data is less than the size of the input data. Is there any statistical reason behind this? In my case 100K is the size of the input and it gives 999,98 sized output
I'm wondering what is causing this problem. Thanks in advance

Code:

```
listofsentences=[]
for sent in x_train:
    listofsentences.append(sent.split())

training_model = Word2Vec(sentences=listofsentences, workers=-1,min_count=5)
modelwords = list(training_model.wv.vocab)

std_avgw2v_x_train = []
for everysentence in tqdm(listofsentences):
    count = 0
    sentence = np.zeros(100)
    for everyword in everysentence:
        if everyword in modelwords:
            w2v = training_model.wv[everyword]
            count += 1
            sentence += w2v

    if count != 0:
        sentence/=count
        std_avgw2v_x_train.append(sentence)

len(std_avgw2v_x_train)
>99998

len(x_train)
>100000
```

EDIT1: I'd like to mention that I Just started learning ML, Its been 55 days since I started. Also, the same code gives our 100K output samples While I vectorize with TFIDFW2V

I have attached the image of the same. Kindly look into it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue can be one of the two :

A . You have missing value in `x_train`

B . One of the values in `x_train` has no word that is there in `modelwords`.

In both the cases ,

`if everyword in modelwords:
     w2v = training_model.wv[everyword]
     count += 1
     sentence += w2v`

condition doesn't get satisfied and you end up not addding any new value to `sentence`

Comment: Thanks! I'll check the same and update the question. BTW, The same input when I vectorize via TFIDFW2V Gives out 100K samples as output

Comment: Since , tf-idf creates a vector based on the corpus only , it accounts for all the words unlike here where you are comparing if the word is present in the w2v vocab or not.

Comment: A: Thanks, To Check for any missing data, I tried converting this to a dataframe and sorted indices wtih attribute na_position='first' and I couldn't find any missing values interpreted as Na or any empty spaces and also I performed df.dropna(inplace=True) and the size of the dataset still remains (100000,1)

Comment: B: I tried some words that are not in the vocabulary. For example, 
When I tried `w2v = training_model.wv['hi']` and this gave me `KeyError: "word 'hi' not in vocabulary"`
So this means, Your Suggestion B also is not the problem here right??
Correct me if I'm wrong. Also if you can suggest anyother robust methods for checking the problem, I would try that. Thanks